# Show website 'likes' on facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page

About 1 week ago we launched a new website. We've setup a facebook app and integrated the facebook like button using that app ID.

The site has had a great amount of traffic and now the website has over 10,000 likes, which is great....

In hindsight though, we should have targeted the facebook like button to like a facebook page instead of the website, so that we can interact with the 'likers'.

We've created a facebook page now, and linked it with our app. Is there a way for the number of 'likes' on our facebook page to be the 10,000 likes we have showing on the website?

Comment: NO, there isn't. It's counted separately.

Comment: Thanks @Tobi - figured as much, but had to check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Every URL is counted separately. If you create a Facebook Page, this is another entity within the Graph API, so the likes cannot be shared.